# How to create a JS library with remote assets?

Tags: sdk, javascript

I'm building a JS SDK (Library) and I'm planning on giving the users only a JS loader which in turn should load all the assets from a CDN (so we can deploy new code without asking clients to download new versions of the SDK).

The Assets include all the SDK Code, some CSS files, config files and some graphics.

The Javascript code depends on the config files (which should be loaded prior to using the SDK) and the library load should fail if any of the assets fails (for example, a jpeg can't be downloaded).

Just a note - I can't use an IFrame as I need to interact with the hosting page.

How can I accomplish this? Any best practices?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried easyXDM?

Answer (score 0):

easyXDM is a Javascript library that enables you as a developer to easily work around the limitation set in place by the Same Origin Policy, in turn making it easy to communicate and expose javascript API’s across domain boundaries.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how this solves the issue of loading CSS/Config/Etc... files and making sure they're all loaded in the correct sequence and maintain their dependencies (JS depends on the Config for example)